# Is there a significant difference in assigning values one-by-one and with tuples in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

Is there a big difference between two statement in time required, memory usage or something:

```
(script_name, option1, option2) = (sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

and

```
script_name = sys.argv[0]
option1 = sys.argv[1]
option2 = sys.argv[2]
```

(assuming no `optparse` used)

Comment: I would use the first one, but as `script_name, option1, option2 = sys.argv` (or `sys.argv[:3]`), otherwise there's no point!

Comment: Really, for lines that get executed *just once* **stop worrying about time or memory usage**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yours seems more convenient!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, kinda silly question. But I'm really curious! Haha.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Some surprisingly simple lines that are executed just once can take quite a lot of memory and time even starting from a moderate data set. Kinda comes with the high level language deal. However, many of them are contrived and those that *are* worth worrying about will often stick out like a sore thumb the second you run the program, so your point still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No significant difference. Thanks to bytecode peephole optimizations, there's not even a temporary tuple construction in the first one. Even if there was, tuples are dirt cheap to create and dispose of.

Personally I'd write it as

```
script_name, option1, option2, *_ = sys.argv # or
script_name, option1, option2 = sys.argv[:3]
```

I feel obligated to point out that this raises a different, perhaps more confusing, error message if there are too few command-line arguments, but since a *good* error message requires an explicit check beforehand anyway, I don't mind.

Comment: What is that `*_`? I put it in my code, it throws `invalid systax`

Comment: you just need `script_name, option1, option2 = sys.argv`

Comment: @Jeon It's a Python 3 feature meaning "Ignore the rest" (specifically, stuff the remaining arguments into `_`). In Python 2 I'd write `script_name, option1, option2 = sys.argv[:3]`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Only if there are always exactly two command line arguments.